# How to create optional RewriteCond in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i have touble for my .htaccess config., this is part of config:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^token=(.*)
RewriteRule ^aplikasi/(.*).asp aplikasi.php?halaman=$1&token=%1
```

and result that config is:

```
http://{domain}/aplikasi/{$1}.asp?token={%1}
```

if i using this link:

```
http://{domain}/aplikasi/{$1}.asp
```

i have 404 error, i my question is : how to create like that with optional token prameter (i want to "?token={%1}" is optional)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two possibilities.

### If you want to allow either an empty query string or only `token`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^token=([^&\s]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^aplikasi/(.+)\.asp$ /aplikasi.php?halaman=$1&token=%1 [L]
```

### If you want to allow any query string

```
RewriteRule ^aplikasi/(.+)\.asp$ /aplikasi.php?halaman=$1 [L,QSA]
```